# Xcode Bot "Can't fit data in the buffer (-1)"

Tags: xcode, xcode-bots, xcode-server

We're trying to set up a CI server on OS X 10.10.4, under Xcode Server 4.1.3 beta (build 14S1113) running Xcode 6.4 (6E35b). We got it to work when we set it up on Friday, but when we came in this morning it was up to 3500-odd integrations, all failing with the following error:

```
Build Service Error: Can't fit data in the buffer (-1).
```

We've since nuked and re-installed the whole machine and installed the versions of the apps noted above and still get the same result. We found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125829/os-x-server-bot-cant-get-source-from-repository) question, but it doesn't seem relevant as it's over nine months old.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Filed as rdar://21702586

Comment: which git are you using?  I ran into that issue when I was using a git repository that was built on jgit.  and the previous question that you reference was indeed the solution

Comment: The really odd thing is that it worked once.

Comment: yea that is strange, try running a test project off github or bitbucket, any luck with that?

Comment: We have proxied our real (TFS) repo behind an internal GitHub repo and it seems to be working again. At this point I suppose we just wait it out until updates to Xcode or our TFS installation make the problem go away?

Comment: I would say thats probably your best bet, as I wound up doing a similar thing with my issue.  Glad to hear you've got it working though, Xcode bots are surprisingly a lot of work